# Java WorldWind : how to access AnalyticSurface on DragEvent

Tags: java, reflection, protected, worldwind

I am using extensively Java worldwind for an application displaying data over rectangular sector. I want to be able to drag this data over the globe. Such behavior is already implemented in WorldWind for shapes such as [SurfaceCircle](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/render/SurfaceCircle.html)(implementing [Movable](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/Movable.html)) as demonstrated through [BasicDragger](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/util/BasicDragger.html).

I am trying to implement such behavior for [AnalyticSurface](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwindx/examples/analytics/AnalyticSurface.html) (not implementing Moveable). problem is that [DragSelectEvent](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/event/DragSelectEvent.html).getTopObject returns me a protected static class called [AnalyticSurface.ClampToGroundSurface](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwindx/examples/analytics/AnalyticSurface.ClampToGroundSurface.html) with no public accessor to my AnalyticSurface.

To sum up : I created an object and I display it in 3d earth rendering, and drag event initiated onto this graphical representation returns me an object with no public accessor to my own object, hence no way to modify it following the mouse behavior.

It seems like an architecture mistake on WorldWind side. With no use of reflection, is there a way to access my own object linked to my drag event ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is extend `AnalyticSurface` and implement `Movable`, then you can just use `BasicDragger` instead of writing your own select listener.

```
public class DraggableAnalyticSurface extends AnalyticSurface implements Movable {
    @Override
    public Position getReferencePosition() {
        return this.referencePos;
    }

    @Override
    public void move(Position position) {
        // not needed by BasicDragger
    }

    @Override
    public void moveTo(Position position) {
        final double latDelta = this.referencePos.getLatitude().degrees
                                - position.getLatitude().degrees;
        final double lonDelta = this.referencePos.getLongitude().degrees
                                - position.getLongitude().degrees;

        final double newMinLat = this.sector.getMinLatitude().degrees - latDelta;
        final double newMinLon = this.sector.getMinLongitude().degrees - lonDelta;
        final double newMaxLat = this.sector.getMaxLatitude().degrees - latDelta;
        final double newMaxLon = this.sector.getMaxLongitude().degrees - lonDelta;

        this.setSector(Sector.fromDegrees(newMinLat, newMaxLat, newMinLon, newMaxLon));
    }
}
```